# Algorithm for checking if a given embedding is planar in less than $O(n^2)$ time.

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computational-geometry, planar-graphs

Given an embedding of a graph (with that I mean a concrete spacial layout of the graph on the 2D plane with only $n$ straight edges. Is this the right terminology?), how can I determine if that embedding is planar?

Just for clarification, this would be a planar embedding:
[image]

while this would not be a planar embedding:[image]

The graph itself is of course planar both times, but since AD and BC cross in the second embedding, that embedding is not planar.

A simple solution would of course be to test if any of the edges intersect, but that is an $O(n^2)$ operation, which may be too slow for my purposes. Since there are algorithms for determining if a graph is planar in linear time, I hoped that there would also be algorithms for determining if an embedding is planar (since that seems like an easier problem), but all algorithms I can find are either used to draw an embedding, generate an embedding, or check if a graph is planar.

I am not interested in creating a planar embedding, I need to determine if a given embedding is planar. It would also be useful if the algorithm could determine which edges violate the planarity, but that is not a requirement.

Comment: [This](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-a-set-of-line-segments-find-if-any-two-segments-intersect/) sounds applicable

Comment: Indeed, this solves my problem, thanks! Do you want to give it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [sweep line algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-a-set-of-line-segments-find-if-any-two-segments-intersect/) sounds like what you need.